# Give a "Not a duplicate button" on a question

Tags: feature-request

EDIT: This is NOT a duplicate of [the other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not), as this is a feature request.

**Expected wording:**

> Your post has been associated with a similar question. If that question doesn’t resolve your question, edit this question.

Also, the Delete question button should be removed as it would lead to a question ban.

[image]

For [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354612/paste-image-directly) question, it has a wrong duplicate. The feedback recommends asking a new one. Why do we have to re-create the same question? Can we have a button as Not a Duplicate?

This alert box seems to be appropriate.
[image]

Comment: So there is no need to ask a new question?

Comment: The "Edit Question" button already *is* the "Not A Duplicate" button. If you don't think the dupe-target answers your question, you can edit your question to explain *why* the dupe-target doesn't answer your question.

Comment: _"The feedback recommends asking a new one"_ The feedback is **misleading**. "ask a new one" means (or at least should mean) a _different_ one. This has been reported [multiple](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394887/8967612) [times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394552/8967612) and gets mistaken a lot but for some reason hasn't been changed. If you believe your question isn't a duplicate, edit it and explain exactly how it's different from the target dup.

Comment: @41686d6564, that for closed, it's about duplicate

Comment: @SmartManoj A duplicate question is a closed question. Being duplicate is one of the reasons the community chooses when _closing_ a question. If you look at your screenshot above of the post notice, it says "**Closed** 2 mins ago".

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/282094 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354672/282094

Comment: Alternate duplicate as to this being a FR: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309996/rewording-of-the-duplicate-notice-to-communicate-better

Comment: "The "Edit Question" button already is the "Not A Duplicate" button" - It doesn't make that clear. The instructions literally say "if this doesn't answer your question, ask a new one". The instructions should say "If this doesn't answer your question, click the Edit button to clarify what you're asking".

Answer (score 5):

No.  The Edit button already does this.  If you think that your question is *not* a duplicate, then [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/354614/edit) it and explain that (and how) the duplicate target doesn't answer your question.

Comment: this answer should be included in the feedback

Comment: I agree with @SmartManoj.
The instructions literally tell you to ask a new question (not edit the current question) if the similar question doesn't answer your question.