# 99 reputation yet getting "Earn 10 reputation in order to answer this question"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, privileges, protected-questions

Asking this here because I think this is very likely to be a general behaviour.

Some months ago I wrote an [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/408650/259428) to a question in Software Engineering that got very bad feedback (two negative votes and one delete) which then made me get 99 of reputation.

Now, I see this in the page

> [Highly active question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). Earn 10 reputation in order to answer this
> question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from
> spam and non-answer activity.

[image: 99 reputation yet getting the warning]

Understand that I was awarded 100 in reputation in that specific network due to having good reputation in other communities. Still, the description in the Highly active question page also mentions

> Protecting a question prevents answers from being added by anonymous
> and very low-reputation users, generally users with under 10
> reputation.

and I don't have under 10 reputation. So, either it should be clearer that "Highly active question" blockage can also apply to users with more than 10 of reputation OR give such users the permission to do so.

---

### Edit

According to [Ollie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354618/364217)'s answer it's intentional that such users don't have the respective privilege. So, this question is then only proposing to add the content from Ollie's answer (see right after) in the [**protected question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions)'s page.

> The +100 reputation Association Bonus is ignored in such cases.  From
> the post [What is the Association Bonus and how does it work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work):
>
> > In other words, a user with the association bonus and no other rep changes can't answer protected questions.
>
> Also:
>
> > On per-site metas, you can answer protected questions with the association bonus reputation, provided your corresponding main site
> > reputation doesn't fall below 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the association bonus, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: The +100 reputation bonus is ignored in such cases.  But I do agree that maybe it should be a little clearer to avoid confusing new users.

Comment: @Turamarth while that's a good question, it doesn't address the implications in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The +100 reputation Association Bonus is ignored in such cases.  From the post [What is the Association Bonus and how does it work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work):

> In other words, a user with the association bonus and no other rep changes can't answer protected questions.

Also:

> On per-site metas, you can answer protected questions with the association bonus reputation, provided your corresponding main site reputation doesn't fall below 10.

Comment: That would be great information to include in the [protect questions page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions).

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 Hmm...Perhaps you could make a feature-request about that.

Comment: So another question or that is implied in this particular one?

Comment: No need to answer dupe questions

Comment: @Luuklag Whoops...Won't do it again.  Hang on - is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354614/give-a-not-a-duplicate-button-on-a-question/354619#354619) a duplicate?

Comment: @Ollie not really. It was more about there's a particular behaviour and as things are atm there's something wrong and so we ought to fix for A or for B. You clarified why it should be fixed for B instead.

Comment: @Ollie there are a lot of these "simple" questions that have been asked before. Some users notice such a post and vote to close, but then you need to be around for some time to remember it was asked before.