# Include "the association bonus doesn't count" message in a protected question label

Tags: feature-request, protected-questions, association-bonus

While reading a deleted post from Meta Stack Exchange at https://web.archive.org, I saw one of the older "protected question" labels:

[image]

And then I saw one of the newer protected labels (this is a screenshot from a screenshot):

[image]

I kind of preferred the older version of the protected question label, or the text at least.  Saying that the association bonus doesn't count for checks like that helped [avoid confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354617/99-reputation-yet-getting-earn-10-reputation-in-order-to-answer-this-question/354618#354618) for newer users (and some older ones too).  Removing that message causes confusion to some new users with the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work).

**Feature request:**  Could we add that message back into the protected question labels, as it will be clearer and a bit more accurate?

Comment: If you feel that this request has additional arguments that aren't in the question itself, feel free to post an answer (or edit them in if they're small).

Comment: You noticed that the older messages mentioned the disqualification of the association bonus and that the new ones don't? Huh, interesting. You might want to consider posting that as a comment on the other question that your post is a dupe of.

Comment: @mindstormsboi Yep, [done that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349543/protected-question-notice-is-confusing-and-incorrect-especially-to-users-with-t#comment1185019_349543).