# Info box on duplicate question states you should ask a new one instead of editing the original question

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

A couple of days ago I asked a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64061645/why-has-stringbuilder-append-not-overload-for-formattablestring). The question was marked as duplicate. The linked question did not answer my question, so according to the info box, I [posted the question again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64066084/why-has-stringbuilder-append-not-overload-for-formattablestring-no-duplicate) (and received a helpful comment before the 2nd question was closed as duplicate of the 1st question). A user commented that I should have edited the 1st question instead of opening the 2nd one. Doing some research, I also found [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) about reopening question.

How can I suggest to change the text on the info box so it clearly states that one should edit the question instead of creating a new one?

Btw here is the current text of the info box

> Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this
> question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.

Comment: The screenshot on that post shows an info box that suggests to either edit or post a new question. The info box I got only shows the above text, so it only suggests to ask a new question. Has the info box changes recently? With the text in the screenshot, I would not have opened another question.

Comment: wertzui, this [duplicate is status-declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339734/282094) and locked; yet is also a close duplicate.